# What is a formal name "UA" in GA Tracking ID?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a little question about extended e-commerce (GA plugin), so forgive me to ask this question.

I'm Japanese front-end engineer and trying to introduce the extended E-commerce plugin in my EC-site. While developing with a colleague, he pointed out my coding comment about UA.

```
// my comment: this is a point that we provide UserAgent for GA.
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
```

Colleague: "UA does not mean 'User Agent', because 'User Agent' is related to Browser or HTTPS header. At least your comment does not make sense."

We discussed about this small issue, but we could not reach satisfactory conclusion. I guess this is not directly related to programming, but I would like to know the other opinions.

Comment: Thank you for your all comments and reference.
I could learn the history about GA and where the name 'UA' derived from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The letters "UA" in a Google Tracking ID stand for *Urchin Analytics* (reference [here](http://blog.oribi.io/google-analytics-tracking-id/)). Urchin was a product that was acquired by Google in 2005 (see [Дмитро Булах's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59498101/what-is-a-formal-name-ua-in-ga-tracking-id/59498514#59498514)).

The structure of the Tracking ID is:

```
UA-000000-2
```

The first set of numbers (-000000, in the example above) refers to your account number, and the second set of numbers (-2) refers to the specific property number associated with the account.

Comment: UA-prefix was there long before Universal Analytics was rolled out.

Comment: You are correct. I have updated my answer and inserted a reference to yours.

Answer (score 1):

It's from "Urchin Analytics". Urchin was acquired by Google in 2005[image]